# Recording incoming phone number and terminating the call serverside

Tags: python, sip

What would you recommend for this scenario:

I have phone number connected to SIP at phone.ipkall.com.
I want to register incoming phone number (in DB) 
and terminate call on Linux server so the user don't get billed.

In similar questions people mentioned http://sip2sip.info and
http://www.b2bua.org/.

What would be a shortest path to do this scenario?
(Preferably in python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the SIP application platforms will easily be able to do that for you although most likely you'll only be able to get them as far as submitting a HTTP request so you'll need to set up a web front end to your database.

Some of the SIP application platforms available are anveo.com, tropo.com, twilio.com and my own sipsorcery.com. In the case of the latter (my own service) there is a facility to record key/value pairs to a database so depending on what you need to do with the recorded caller ID that may be adequate without requiring your own database.